# ReactJS memory leak while async tasks & subscriptions

Tags: reactjs

In my react app I am making API call using axios. But, in my console, I got an error 
"Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method."
My code is below

To fix the memory leak, I added _isMounted check and consoled the _ismounted. My app is rendered twice.
First-time console prints _isMounted status true and then false (due to componentDidMount) but then the app is rendered second time & _isMounted in the console is printed as true.

```
app.jsx
export class Test extends Component {
_isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apiData: null
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    API.callAPI(this.setStateHandler, this._isMounted)
  }
  setStateHandler = (state) => {
    this.setState(state);
  }
 componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false
  }
 render() {
  return(...)}

api.js
callAPI = (setStateHandler, _isMounted) => {
    axios.get('/article', {headers: {Authorization: token}})
    .then((response) => {
      if(_isMounted) {
        setStateHandler({ programs: response.data.data.programs });
      }
    })
  }
```

1. I would like to fix my memory leak issue. How should I fix that?
2. Why is my application rendered twice and the second time componentDidUnmount is not called?

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_isMounted` argument passed in to `callAPI` will not change when your component is unmounted.

You could instead return the data to the component and check if `this._isMounted` is still `true` there instead.

**Example**

```
// App.jsx
export class Test extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  state = { programs: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;

    API.callAPI().then(data => {
      if (this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({ programs: data.data.programs });
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}

// api.js
const callAPI = () => {
  return axios
    .get("/article", { headers: { Authorization: token } })
    .then(response => response.data);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Tholle ... The memory leak issue got fixed. But my app is rendering 3 times. First time render(), didMount() & WillUnmount() is running then render(), DidMount() & on 3rd render app is rendered fully. Is that normal ... rendering 3 times?

Comment: @TEMP Great! You at least have to render 2 times: The initial render, and the second render when you do `setState` in the `callAPI` callback. I'm not sure where the third render comes from, and it will be hard to tell without seeing more code. I wouldn't worry about it though.

Comment: Ok ... @Tholle I'm using _isMounted which is the deprecated solution to the memory leak. Can you suggest me any other solution? Thanks, sorry for asking another question

Comment: @TEMP Using the function `this.isMounted()` is deprecated, but storing an instance variable like you do called e.g. `_isMounted` or `_isAlive` or whatever you prefer is still a valid solution. If you still are not sure if it's good or not, consider opening up another question as this one has been answered.